# Shell Script for obtain files in directory to command line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

Script for selecting all files in directory to command line, so that it simplifies the selection process for that command.

for example:

```
$ command file1 file2 file3 ....
```

it wont take * for select all.

Comment: What's wrong with `command *` ?

Comment: Would you like hidden files as well `.filename`

Answer (score 0):

Too select all the files in a directory you can use `find . -type f` and use the `-exec` option to execute tour command.

```
find . -type f -exec command {} \;
```

Comment: your ls would select directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cat `find . -type f -print -maxdepth 1`--although you could do with ls as well
```

Comment: Why on earth are you opening a subshell and then `cat`ing it ? Also you should put maxdepth before type or you will get a warning.

Comment: @Jidder i used cat as sample because OP didn't mentioned command. He might use something is my assumption.

Comment: That would pass the output to the command as one argument though ? Wouldn't it be better to use xargs or exec ?

Comment: sure but that's not what i think OP wanted. He wanted list of files so his command if you look is "command file1 file2 file3..."

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back-tics use parentheses: `cat $(find . .....)`

Comment: Ya, it's should be `YourCommand \`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print\``.  `cat` ing is just an example of "YourCommand".  As the question is asking to simplify the command line: a command substitution fits in the gap to get all files in one line.  And yes, `-maxdepth` should go first.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1A

-> 
file1.txt
file2.txt
LastFile.idx
```

but why * is does not suite ?

list all files on the same line (as argument) but separated by `,`

```
ls -1am

->
file1.txt, file2.txt, LastFile.idx
```

each files in encapsuled in double quote

```
$( ls -1am | sed 's/, /" "/g;s/.*/"&"/' )

->
"file1.txt" "file2.txt" "LastFile.idx"
```

Comment: Won't this do directories as well ?

Comment: It return the directory name but don't goes inside. Add info for a "one line argument"

Comment: I don't know what you mean by  `Add info for a "one line argument"`